# Is this grammatically correct or not?

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

I have a question. Is this sentence correct grammatically??

```
What have you tried for it?
```

Or I should use this instead :

```
Have you tried anything for it?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sound like things you would ask someone with a medical condition. You can use either. If you think the person may have tried at least one remedy, you could ask "What have you tried for it?", or if you are not sure, you could ask "Have you tried anything for it?".

Comment: Thanks, I just want to know both sentences are correct grammatically or not. so the answer is yes!